# Book about a boy who finds a floating black orb and when he touches it, it takes him back to the time of Jesus

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

When I was in elementary school I remember reading a book about a boy who found a floating orb and when he touched it he got transported to the time of Jesus, and then he ends up staying and watching the crucifixion of Jesus and walks with the disciples to the cave. I cannot remember much else, but am so curious on what the book is. I remember the cover being grey and black and having an orb on the front.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are thinking of the book *Kingdoms and Conquerors* from the Tennis Shoes Adventure Series. In it a boy and members of his family find and return to a cave many times throughout the series and time travel to various points along biblical and pre Colombian America following the events outlined in the Book of Mormon.

The orb you mentioned could be cave’s “power source” mentioned in the book for time travel and was becoming unstable. This cave could also transport the characters through time and to different locations in time depending on the book.

There are other similarities to what you mentioned in your question but admittedly they vary slightly from your description.